# SQL Server error JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '?' is found at position 21

Tags: sql-server, json, varchar, unicode

I am getting below error while parsing any JSON string with special character or emoji. How to parse this?

> JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '?' is found at position 21.

Sample code:

```
DECLARE @OriginalJSON NVARCHAR(4000), @newvalue varchar(30),@path varchar(20)
  Set @OriginalJSON='{
    "test2": "ＲＯＹＤ＼ロイド",
    "test1": 0
  }'
   Select
        @OriginalJSON,
        JSON_VALUE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),@OriginalJSON), '$.test1')  AS 'Updated JSON';
```

Is there any way to parse this data without modifying it? This is just sample code. I need to query from a table and cannot modify the data.

Comment: Eric showed how to fix the bad data in his answer but it would be best to fix the app code so that only valid json is stored.

Comment: @DanGuzman It's not a backslash, the mistake is the lack of the `N'` prefix

Comment: @Charlieface, there are multiple mistakes as you mentioned in your answer. I didn't see the malformed json with the backslash was introduced by the non-Unicode types.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the REPLACE function can be used to find backslashes and replace them with a double backslash.

Note that if there are already double backslashes in your data, you'll end up with four of them.

This may be enough to get you around the errors and on your way, though. I've altered your example slightly to make data types match as much as possible.

```
DECLARE 
    @OriginalJSON nvarchar(max), 
    @newvalue nvarchar(30),
    @path nvarchar(20);
  
SET @OriginalJSON = N'{
    "test2": "ＲＯＹＤ＼ロイド",
    "test1": 0
  }';
   
SELECT
    @OriginalJSON,
    JSON_VALUE
    (
        CONVERT
        (
            nvarchar(MAX),
            REPLACE(REPLACE(
                @OriginalJSON,
            NCHAR(92), NCHAR(92) + NCHAR(92)),
            NCHAR(65340), NCHAR(65340) + NCHAR(65340))
        ), 
        '$.test1'
    )  AS 'Updated JSON';
```

Comment: This is working.

Comment: @Mish if this solution is okay with you, use the voting/accepting buttons to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The weird character `＼` in your JSON `U+FF3C : FULLWIDTH REVERSE SOLIDUS` is being converted into a normal backslash `\`, which needs to be escaped with another backslash.

The reason this is happening is two-fold:

- You are not prefixing your JSON string with `N` which means it becomes a `varchar` string under the current code page. Prefixing it with `N` keeps it as UTF-16.
- You also have an unnecessary `CONVERT`. At the very least it should be `nvarchar` not `varchar`.

The below works fine, and does not muck around with any characters:

```sql
DECLARE @OriginalJSON NVARCHAR(MAX), @newvalue varchar(30),@path varchar(20)
SET @OriginalJSON = N'{
    "test2": "ＲＯＹＤ＼ロイド",
    "test1": 0
  }';
SELECT 
        @OriginalJSON,
        JSON_VALUE(@OriginalJSON, '$.test1')  AS 'Updated JSON';
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/iKm5BN1B)

Note that JSON should always be stored in `nvarchar(max)` anyway